# Generation has thrown an exception: but there is no exception and it wont generate the rig correctly. how do I fix this?

Tags: rigging, error, rigify

So, I have fixed many errors in my bone structure but when I try to generate the rig it says "Generation has thrown an exception:" and that's it. I've generated the rig multiple times tweaking a thing here and there but end up doing ctrl z so I don't have a broken rig. I have no idea how to fix this problem and couldn't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the file you're working on, going in the outliner, changing it from "view layer" to "orphan data" and click the "purge" button many times, until only brushes remain, then generate.

Try also the advanced options, choosing to generate a new rig with a new rig name, instead of overwriting the previous rig.

Try also to append the metarig into a new file and generate from there.[image]

If the problem persist, please upload your file.